# Java scanner error after running

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
```

Following are the error listed below
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
        at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1465)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
        at ticketBook.run.main(run.java:22)
    Please Help me.

Comment: You must show some code when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm) and add the jar file into library folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

What is the mysql version of your database ??....download the jar for that version and ensure its on your class path...when you are running your application......